# UUID conflict of two disks having same Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, mount

Cloned Ubuntu 20.04 from m.2 SSD to nvme SSD. UUID on nvme newly generated after cloning. Both are working but with following rider :
The UUID in fstab of nvme ubuntu must be the UUID of SSD ubuntu otherwise gives error " Failed to start Remount Root and Kernel Filesystems".
But both Ubuntu partitions are working independently as the nvme version version is updated to 20.04.03 from 20.04.01 originally. The version on SSD is still 20.04.01.
If the respective UUID entered in fstab then both partitions are not booting up.
I am having legacy boot BIOS and using Clover bootloader having GPT fs on both the disks.

```
$ lsblk -o name,size,fstype,label,uuid,mountpoint,model|sed 's/ *$//';
NAME          SIZE FSTYPE   LABEL            UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT                        MODEL    
loop0       185.4M squashfs                                                       /snap/audacity/920    
loop1       185.3M squashfs                                                       /snap/audacity/922    
loop2           4K squashfs                                                       /snap/bare/5    
loop3        99.4M squashfs                                                       /snap/core/11993    
loop4        61.9M squashfs                                                       /snap/core20/1169    
loop5        99.5M squashfs                                                       /snap/core/11798    
loop6        55.4M squashfs                                                       /snap/core18/2128    
loop7         219M squashfs                                                       /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/66    
loop8        55.5M squashfs                                                       /snap/core18/2246    
loop9        61.8M squashfs                                                       /snap/core20/1081    
loop10        140K squashfs                                                       /snap/gtk2-common-themes/13    
loop11       65.2M squashfs                                                       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1519    
loop12        219M squashfs                                                       /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/72    
loop13       32.4M squashfs                                                       /snap/snapd/13270    
loop14         51M squashfs                                                       /snap/snap-store/542    
loop15       65.1M squashfs                                                       /snap/gtk-common-themes/1515    
loop16       42.2M squashfs                                                       /snap/snapd/13831    
loop17      164.8M squashfs                                                       /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/161    
loop18         51M squashfs                                                       /snap/snap-store/547    
loop19      162.9M squashfs                                                       /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/145    
sda         119.2G                                                                                             LS_128GB_M300    
├─sda1         24G ext4     U20.04 64bit SSD 11bb7e9e-49c9-4e44-bc97-2b501f358e2b    
├─sda2        555M vfat     EFI-SSD          864B-9B3E    
├─sda3         45G ntfs                      F894575794571788    
├─sda4      102.9M vfat     BDU-SSD          64BD-803B    
├─sda5        500M ext4                      2a2cb9ea-cb10-4154-ac48-8c8513559de3    
└─sda6       49.2G ntfs                      6C7A63467A630BE0    
sdb            29G                                                                                             Storage_Device    
├─sdb1        200M vfat     BDU              7CCC-3457                            /boot/efi    
└─sdb2       28.8G    
nvme0n1     232.9G                                                                                             Samsung SSD 970         EVO Plus 250GB    
├─nvme0n1p1   100M vfat     BDU-NVME         4860-509F    
├─nvme0n1p2  46.5G ext4     U20.04 64bit SSD 5d01e76f-5114-4416-b810-5de33dafa914 /    
└─nvme0n1p3  49.6G ext4     U18 NVME         fd23fb07-2a0d-4b9c-962f-1d86f17e32df
```

fstab of ubuntu 20.04 on SSD

```
#/etc/fstab: static file system information.
#Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
#device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
#that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#<file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
#/ was on /dev/sda1 during installation
#UUID=5d01e76f-5114-4416-b810-5de33dafa914 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
UUID=11bb7e9e-49c9-4e44-bc97-2b501f358e2b /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1 /swapfile         
none            swap    sw              0       0
#UUID=4860-509F  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults      0       1
#UUID=4860-509F  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults      0       1
#UUID=4860-509F  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults      0       1
#UUID=4860-509F  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults      0       1
#UUID=B092-D69A  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults      0       1
#UUID=864B-9B3E  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults      0       1
#UUID=864B-9B3E  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults      0       1 
 UUID=864B-9B3E  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults      0       1
```

fstab of ubuntu of 20.04 on NVME

```
#/etc/fstab: static file system information.
#Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
#device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
#That works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#<file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
#/ was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=11bb7e9e-49c9-4e44-bc97-2b501f358e2b /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
#UUID=5d01e76f-5114-4416-b810-5de33dafa314 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID=4860-509F  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults      0       1
```

**Issue resolved by going through the Update #1 in the answer below.**

Comment: @heynnema pls see the appended lsblk output in the orginal question edit. The UUID of cloned partition at nvme0n1p2 is already unique whether I still have to do 'man uuidgen and man tune2fs' as suggested by you. Thanks.

Comment: Is your intent to keep both SSD and NVME connected? You didn't clone the disks, you probably used gparted copy/paste partitions, and then altered the partition sizes, yes? If you're using legacy boot, why are the disks GPT? Show me your /etc/fstab.

Comment: @heynnema yes through gparted I did copy/paste and also changed its UUID. and altered its size.. My desktop is having legacy BIOS and since nvme SSD can't be booted through it I am using Clover bootloader which requires GPT. Which /etc/fstab you want, of ssd's or nvme's ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: Go ahead and show me both. Do you switch depending on the hardware configuration?

Comment: @heynnema pls see the fstab of both the disks.

Comment: I guess that I'm confused. What is the final config you want... two disks, always connected, and boot from nvme... or something else? Why two fstabs? The UUIDs look wrong in the nvme fstab. 5d01e76f-5114-4416-b810-5de33dafa314 should end in a914.

Comment: See Update #1 in my answer.

Comment: @heynnema pls see my reply just below your Update #1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you clone a disk, **everything** gets cloned, including the disk and partition UUIDs. That becomes a problem when both disks are connected to the system at the same time.

You need to change the UUID on the original disk, or the clone disk. However, if you change the UUID on the original disk, you'll have to also edit /etc/fstab. If you change the UUID on the clone disk, no /etc/fstab edits are required (unless the clone disk is eventually installed into the system, in place of the original disk, and then /etc/fstab will need to be updated with the new UUID, or /dev/sdaX device name).

**Note**: There should be no reason to mount both the original disk, and the cloned disk, by additional edits to /etc/fstab. A clone disk is normally used to create a backup, or to transfer from a smaller original disk, to a larger clone disk, and then exchanged in the system.

**Note**: Clone disk booting issues can normally be fixed by the use of `boot-repair`.

There are two commands required to make UUID changes. See the following man pages...

```
man uuidgen
man tune2fs
```

**uuidgen**

**example**: `uuidgen -r` or `uuidgen -t`

```
   -r, --random
          Generate a random-based UUID.  This method creates a  UUID  con‐
          sisting  mostly  of random bits.  It requires that the operating
          system have a high quality  random  number  generator,  such  as
          /dev/random.

   -t, --time
          Generate a time-based UUID.  This method creates a UUID based on
          the system clock plus the system's ethernet hardware address, if
          present.
```

**tune2fs**

**example**: `sudo tune2fs -U new_UUID /dev/sdbX`

```
   -U UUID
          Set the universally unique identifier (UUID) of  the  filesystem
          to UUID.  The format of the UUID is a series of hex digits sepa‐
          rated          by          hyphens,          like          this:
          "c1b9d5a2-f162-11cf-9ece-0020afc76f16".   The UUID parameter may
          also be one of the following:

               clear  clear the filesystem UUID

               random generate a new randomly-generated UUID

               time   generate a new time-based UUID

          The UUID may be used by  mount(8),  fsck(8),  and  /etc/fstab(5)
          (and possibly others) by specifying UUID=uuid instead of a block
          special device name like /dev/hda1.

          See uuidgen(8) for more information.  If  the  system  does  not
          have  a  good  random  number  generator  such as /dev/random or
          /dev/urandom, tune2fs will automatically use a  time-based  UUID
          instead of a randomly-generated UUID.
```

**Update #1:**

corrected fstab of ubuntu of 20.04 on NVME

**Note**: there should be no TABS in fstab, only spaces

```
#/etc/fstab: static file system information.
#Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
#device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
#That works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#<file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
#/ was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
UUID=5d01e76f-5114-4416-b810-5de33dafa914 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID=4860-509F  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults      0       1
```

Comment: "I guess that I'm confused. What is the final config you want... two disks, always connected, and boot from nvme... or something else? Why two fstabs? The UUIDs look wrong in the nvme fstab. 5d01e76f-5114-4416-b810-5de33dafa314 should end in a914"  I want only NVME having ubuntu 20.04 and will remove it from SSD. Not edited any fstab just done copy/paste.  Shall I edit the UUID in NVME fstab. Thanks.

Comment: @prasannaC Yes. Edit the correct UUID into fstab, just like in my Update #1.

Comment: YOU ARE RIGHT!!! the uuid should have ended with a914 instead of a314. Actually that was a silly typo. Thanks a million for your patience and great help. Now I am able to boot my ubuntu 20.04 on partition nvme0n1p2 NVME with SSD disconnected.I accepted your answer.

Comment: @prasannaC Great news! Thanks for the update.